# Intellisense between projects in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, project

I've got a c# project that is full of intellisense comments, and this project compiles to a DLL.

Now when i add this dll as a reference in another project, i do not get intellisense when accessing the members of the original project.

Any ideas how i can get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: Have you added the namespace using `using`

Comment: Of course - it all compiles and works, it's just that i get no intellisense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the project properties, on the Build tab, check the box for "XML documentation file" to have it output XML documentation.  As long as this XML is present in the directory where the dll is referenced from, you should get intellisense.

Comment: OK i've just tried that, it did indeed create the XML files but still no intellisense. Do i need to refresh something?

Comment: Ok somehow my references were pointing to another folder instead of where i thought it would be. So i copied the dlls over there and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense comments? Do you mean the /// comments directly above the method definition? That gets compiled into the assembly. Intellisense should just work.